# ADFS RP Need to Prompt Credentials always

Tags: asp.net, authentication, adfs

We have requirement to implement ADFS to enable SSO with our partner application

1. Application A and Application B are be configured with ADFS for Authentication
2. User launches browser tries to launch application www.appA.com , then we need to redirect to ADFS Login page for authentication
3. After Login user clicks on link for Application B or tries to launch www.AppB.com in web browser, the user should be again redirected to ADFS login page irrespective of if he is authenticated in App A or not.

Kindly guide us How to implement above. If we configure RPs as Web passive, it doesn't ask for login if authenticated in one application.

Comment: Why do you want your user to authenticate again? He/she would enter the same AD credentials as for the first application. ADFS gives you SSO for all apps registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We have requirement to implement ADFS to enable SSO with our partner application"

What you are seeing in exactly what ADFS with SSO delivers. If you sign on with A and B is another RP on that ADFS, then you don't have to re-authenticate. That's what SSO is.

There is no way to invoke AFDS and then not do SSO.